# PyEval_GetLocals returns globals?

Tags: python, c++, boost-python, global, locals

I am trying to access the python locals from the constructor of a C++ class exported with boost.python, but PyEval_GetLocals() seems to return the global instead of local dict. An example: in C++ I do

```
class X {
   public:
      X() {
         boost::python::object locals(boost::python::borrowed(PyEval_GetLocals()));
         locals["xyz"]=42
      }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(test) {
   class_<X>("X", init<>());
}
```

If I now do in Python

```
x = X()
print(xyz)
```

I get '42' as output (as expected). However, the same happens with

```
def fun():
    x = X()

print(xyz)
```

which also prints '42', despite the fact that 'fun()' has created a new scope. I would have expected the 'xyz' name to have gone out of scope again after fun() exits, and thus be left with an undefined 'xyz' by the time I reach the print statement.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any way to get access to the local names from within a C++ object or function?

Comment: Note that even if `PyEval_GetLocals` would give you a proper locals dict, it would give you the locals *of `X::X()`. Lexical scoping blah blah. To manipulate `fun()`'s scope you'd need to mess with frames.

Comment: Fair enough, but what is PyEval_GetLocals supposed to be returning then? There is also a PyEval_GetGlobals, which I took as a pretty strong hint that these two actually return different things. They don't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the testcase may be resulting in a false positive.  Is it possible that you forgot to `del` the `xyz` variable prior to calling `fun()`?

Defining a function creates a variable local to the current scope that refers to the function object.  For example:

```
def fun():
    x = X()
```

Creates a `function` object that is referenced by the `fun` variable within the current scope.  If the function is invoked, then (by default) a new local scope is created, where in the object returned from `X()` will be referenced by `x` within the local scope of the function and not within the caller's frame's `locals()`.

---

Here is an example based on the original code:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

/// @brief Mockup types.
struct X
{
  X()
  {
    // Borrow a reference from the locals dictionary to create a handle.
    // If PyEval_GetLocals() returns NULL, then Boost.Python will throw.
    namespace python = boost::python;
    python::object locals(python::borrowed(PyEval_GetLocals()));

    // Inject a reference to the int(42) object as 'xyz' into the 
    // frame's local variables.
    locals["xyz"] = 42;
  }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::class_<X>("X", python::init<>());
}
```

Interactive usage that asserts visibility:

```python
>>> import example
>>> def fun():
...     assert('xyz' not in locals())
...     x = example.X()
...     assert('xyz' in locals())
...     assert('xyz' not in globals())
... 
>>> assert('xyz' not in globals())
>>> fun()
>>> assert('xyz' not in globals())
>>> x = example.X()
>>> assert('xyz' in globals())
>>> del xyz
>>> fun()
>>> assert('xyz' not in globals())
```

---

For completeness, a [`FuncionType`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#types.FunctionType) can be constructed with a [`CodeType`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#types.CodeType) whose [`co_flags`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#types-and-members) does not have the `newlocals` flag set, causing the frame used for a function's invocation to have its `locals()` return the same as `globals()`.  Here is an interactive usage example demonstrating this:

```python
>>> def fun():
...     x = 42
...     print "local id in fun:", id(locals())
... 
>>> import types
>>> def no_locals(fn):
...     func_code = fn.func_code
...     return types.FunctionType(
...         types.CodeType(
...             func_code.co_argcount,
...             func_code.co_nlocals,
...             func_code.co_stacksize,
...             func_code.co_flags & ~2, # disable newlocals
...             func_code.co_code,
...             func_code.co_consts,
...             func_code.co_names,
...             func_code.co_varnames,
...             func_code.co_filename,
...             func_code.co_name,
...             func_code.co_firstlineno,
...             func_code.co_lnotab),
...         globals())
... 
>>> id(globals())
3075430164L
>>> assert('x' not in locals())
>>> fun()
local id in fun: 3074819588
>>> assert('x' not in locals())
>>> fun = no_locals(fun) # disable newlocals flag for fun
>>> assert('x' not in locals())
>>> fun()
local id in fun: 3075430164
>>> assert('x' in locals())
>>> x
42
```

Even after disabling the `newlocals` flag, I had to invoke `locals()` within `fun()` to observe `x` being inserted into the global symbol table.

Comment: Yeah, my sample actually did work... I'm stupid. Apologies for wasting your time.